# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0. How can I solve?

Tags: dockerfile

I have problem: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount954707384/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

OS: Windows 10
App: VScode